# Polars is throwing an error when I convert from eger to lazy execution

Tags: python-polars

This code works and returns the expected result.

```
import polars as pl 

df = pl.DataFrame({
     'A':[1,2,3,3,2,1],
     'B':[1,1,1,2,2,2]
})

(df
 #.lazy()
 .groupby('B')
 .apply(lambda x: x
 .with_columns(
        [pl.col("A").shift(i).alias(f"A_lag_{i}") for i in range(3)]
    )
 )
  .with_columns(
     [pl.col(f'A_lag_{i}') / pl.col('A') for i in range(3)]
 )
 #.collect()
)
```

However, if you comment out the `.lazy()` and `.collect()` you get a `NotFoundError: f'A_lag_0`

I've tried a few versions of this code, but I can't entirely understand if I'm doing something wrong, or whether this is a bug in Polars.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't address the error that you are receiving, but the more idiomatic way to express this in Polars is to use the [`over`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.over.html#polars.Expr.over) expression.  For example:

```py
(
    df
    .lazy()
    .with_columns([
        pl.col("A").shift(i).over('B').alias(f"A_lag_{i}")
        for i in range(3)])
    .with_columns([
        (pl.col(f"A_lag_{i}") / pl.col("A")).suffix('_result')
        for i in range(3)])
    .collect()
)
```

```
shape: (6, 8)
┌─────┬─────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ A_lag_0 ┆ A_lag_1 ┆ A_lag_2 ┆ A_lag_0_result ┆ A_lag_1_result ┆ A_lag_2_result │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---            ┆ ---            ┆ ---            │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ f64            ┆ f64            ┆ f64            │
╞═════╪═════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1   ┆ 1       ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ 1.0            ┆ null           ┆ null           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 1   ┆ 2       ┆ 1       ┆ null    ┆ 1.0            ┆ 0.5            ┆ null           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 1   ┆ 3       ┆ 2       ┆ 1       ┆ 1.0            ┆ 0.666667       ┆ 0.333333       │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 2   ┆ 3       ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ 1.0            ┆ null           ┆ null           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 2   ┆ 2       ┆ 3       ┆ null    ┆ 1.0            ┆ 1.5            ┆ null           │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 2   ┆ 1       ┆ 2       ┆ 3       ┆ 1.0            ┆ 2.0            ┆ 3.0            │
└─────┴─────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘
```